# Image in asset pipeline not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, prawn, assets

I have seen a number of close problems, but have not been able to find a solution to get solve my problem.  I am using Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3.2.13.

I am using Prawn to generate a PDF, and I a logo to appear.  The logo is found without a problem in the development environment, but fails in the production environment, which is on Heroku.

In my controller I have:

```
def generate_risk_pdf(risk)
    Prawn::Document.new do

      image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo-print.png", :scale => 0.75 if Rails.env.development?
      image "#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('logo-print.png')}", :scale => 0.75 if Rails.env.production?
      move_down 2
      formatted_text [{:text => Exercise Australia", :styles => [:bold], :size => 20}]
      font_size 6
     bounding_box([bounds.right - 150, bounds.bottom], :width => 240, :height => 20) do
        text "Copyright: Exercise Australia, #{Date.today.year}"
      end

   end.render
end
```

The Heroku logs have

> ArgumentError (/assets/logo-print-5b6da7bd4012d953bc1bc749cf934d91.png not found):
>   app/controllers/single_entries_controller.rb:309:in `block in generate_risk_pdf'

Which corresponds to the line above with Rails.env.production?

If I append the URL to /assets/logo-print-5b6da7bd4012d953bc1bc749cf934d91.png the image file exists.

If I remove that line, it works (minus the logo).

Please note this is not only failing for Prawn, but even when I tried to use an image inline for an email.

Please help, I'm tearing my hair out!

Added: Serving from public works- but it is not my preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to:
*rails.root/config/environments/produciton.rb*

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both methods worked for me :

`image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('images/logo-print.png')}"`